# Не отображается карусель с товарами при нажатии кнопки на скрипте показать, скрыть

Tags: javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
      $("A#triggers").toggle(function() { 
        // Отображаем скрытый блок 
         $("DIV#boxs").fadeIn()[0].scrollIntoView(); // fadeIn - плавное появление
      },  
      function() { 
        // Скрываем блок 
        $("DIV#boxs").fadeOut(); // fadeOut - плавное исчезновение 
   return false; // не производить переход по ссылке
      }); // end of toggle() 
    }); // end of ready()
```

Есть работающий код появления, скрытия блока div по кнопке - ссылке. Проблема заключается в том, что в всплывающем блоке boxs, которому присвоен класс display:none находится карусель товаров. При открытии блока div- карусель не отображается, так как была скрыта. почему она не отображается, я так понимаю браузер не читает анимацию при display:none?

Comment: <a class="triggers" href="#">узнать больше →</a> Кому интересен код html - это кнопка, которая отображает div#boxs

Comment: добавьте `html` код карусели и отредактируйте своё сообщение вставив в него код через кнопку в редакторе `Фрагмент кода на js/html/css`

Comment: карусель кастомных слайдов контента на визуальном редакторе wpb для вордперсса

Comment: `При открытии блока div- карусель не отображается, так как была скрыта` - у неё тоже какой-то `display:none` имеется?

Comment: Класс display:none присвоен блоку див, в котрую обернута карусель, нет, никакого класса нет у карусели- присвоил самой карусели блок - не помогло. Такое чувство что она просто даже не грузится , хотя в коде f12 - она есть - но даже когда отклбчаешь в f12 display none- все равно не работает)

Answer (score 0):

Если тебе нужно по нажатию на ссылку отображать/убирать div, то можно так:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.more').on('click', function() {
    $('.abc').fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.abc {
  background: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="more">Привет
  <div class="abc"></div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Желательно конкретно указывать на проблему, тут я вижу 2 варианта:

**1й** - слайдер не инициализируется после появления блока.
**2й** - проблема со стилями этого слайдера.

**Решение 1го варианта:**
Инициализируйте слайдер после вызова функции `fadeIn()`.

**`OwlCarousel`** -  `$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();` или `$('.owl-carousel').initialize();`
**`Swiper`** - `mySwiper.init()`
Если другой - смотрите документацию, она у всех плагинов есть, но у всех разная

**Решение 2го варианта:**

Посмотреть на стили блока где не показывается слайдер.
Если не получается выяснить - покажите код и вам помогут

Как пример покажу этот код:

```js
let swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
});

$('#button').on('click',function(){
  $('#block').css('display', 'block');
});
```

```css
html,body {position: relative;height: 100%;}
body {background: #eee;font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;color:#000;margin: 0;padding: 0;}
.swiper-container, .swiper {width: 100%;height: 100%;}
.swiper-slide {text-align: center;font-size: 18px;background: #fff;display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;}


#block {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button id="button">Click</button>
<div class="swiper" id="block">
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как видите, слайдер не работает как нужно, даже работает но наполовину.

А теперь посмотрим этот код:

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  init: false, // +++
});

$('#button').on('click',function(){
  $('#block').css('display', 'block');
  swiper.init(); // +++
});
```

```css
html,body {position: relative;height: 100%;}
body {background: #eee;font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;color:#000;margin: 0;padding: 0;}
.swiper-container, .swiper {width: 100%;height: 100%;}
.swiper-slide {text-align: center;font-size: 18px;background: #fff;display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;}


#block {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button id="button">Click</button>
<div class="swiper" id="block">
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Тут мы инициализировали его после появления блока.**

Если ответ помог вам решить проблему, пожалуйста поставьте галочку.
На все вопросы по данной теме отвечу - пишите в комментарии, буду рад помочь ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
     function hideBoxsOnStart() {
                $('#boxs').hide();
            }
 setTimeout(hideBoxsOnStart, 1000);
```

Решили при помощи скрытия блока через секунду
Это только часть кода